# Problem regarding taking turns to toss a coin

Tags: probability

> A and B toss a pair of coins in turn, with A tossing first.  A's objective is to obtain TT and B's is to obtain TH(or HT).  The game ends when either player reaches his or her objective, and that player is declared the winner.  Assuming that H appears with probability $p = 1/3$ in each coin.
>
> 1) Find the probability that A is the winner
>
> 2) Find the expected number of tosses of the coins

Comment: For clarification, on their turn they toss *two* coins and tosses from previous turns does not affect things?  In that case, given that it is player $A$'s turn, can you figure out the probability that player $A$ wins *that turn*?  Similarly, if it is player $B$'s turn, what is the probability that player $B$ wins *that turn*?  If those probabilities are $a$ and $b$ respectively, can you reason why the probability $A$ wins at all will be $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a(1-a)^{n}(1-b)^n$ and that $B$ wins will be $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty b(1-a)^{n+1}(1-b)^n$?

Comment: Now, use what you know about geometric series to calculate the respective sums.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't see how you came up with that.  I tried to do it by conditioning but didn't finish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a)

For $A$ to win, he can win in first trial with probability $\frac49$

He can win at third toss with probability $\left( \frac59 \right) \left( \frac59 \right) \left( \frac49 \right)$

He can win at fifth toss with probability $\left[\left( \frac59 \right) \left( \frac59 \right) \right]^2\left( \frac49 \right)$

and so on, we can see that the problem is a geometric sum.

(b)

probability of $TT$ is $\frac49$.

probabilty of $HT$ or $TH$ is also $\frac49$.

Hence it is just a geometric distribution with success probability $\frac49$.

Comment: How did you get 5/9 for part(a)?

Comment: probability of failure is $1-\frac49$.